# Does AppCode provide tools for displaying class dependencies as IntelliJ does?

Tags: intellij-idea, static-analysis, appcode

IntelliJ has a [Dependency Analysis tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/dependency_analysis.html). This tool generates a *"Dependencies Structure Matrix"* that *"reflects the real dependencies between classes in a project"*.

This is how it looks like in IntelliJ:
[image: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/70/dsm/dsmView2.gif]

I would love to see the class dependencies of an Objective-C project as well. Though I couldn't find any AppCode tool providing this feature. Am I overlooking something?